# PHP вложенные try catch

Tags: php, try-catch

Как перехватить Exception в функции на уровне выше?

Например, у меня есть метод:

```
public static function getResponse(string $string)
{
    //.....

    try {
        $response = $this->client->post($this->url, [
                'query' => $queryUrl,
                'body'  => $queryBodyEncoded,
            ] + $this->options);
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        throw new ErrorException($e->getMessage());
    }
    //.....
    }
```

Я вызываю этот метод из своего класса:

```
try {
     myClass::getResponse($string);
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

По итогу все ошибки обрабатываются в первом try catch (вложенном). Как поймать и обработать Exception в моей функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе перехватывается исключение `RequestException` и вызывается `ErrorException`. Соответственно, чтобы перехватить его выше, нужно перехватывать именно `ErrorException`, так как возникает уже именно оно

```
try {
    myClass::getResponse($string);
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Либо оставить как было, но в методе либо вызывать снова `throw new RequestException()`, либо вообще его не перехватывать в методе